connect to network drive vba
I have a workbook that fails to open links from a share drive when a user first logs in as the shared drive shows as "disconnected" until you go to file explorer and open it manually.
After that the links work.
I just want to be able to do this in VBA to prevent the file not found that comes up if the drive is in disconnected state.
I am already using the full UNC file paths and not the drive letters.
Is there a simple code that will reconnect the file path?
I have scrolled through posts to try and find the answer but i cant find what i need.
thanks in advance.

Here is quick ready code to connect a network shared drive and do some operation then disconnect again. Give it a try for your needs.
Public Sub TestNetShareName()
Dim NetworkObject As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Directory As Object
Dim Filename As Object
Dim ServerShare As String
Dim UserName As String
Dim Password As String
Dim i As Long

    ServerShare = "\\192.168.0.10\Tag"
    UserName = "UserName"
    Password = "YourPassword"

    Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password
    ' NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "X:", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password
    ' Use above line to map a network drive with Drive Letter
    Set Directory = FSO.GetFolder(ServerShare)
    i = 1
    For Each Filename In Directory.Files
        Range("A" & i) = Filename.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Set Filename = Nothing
    Set Directory = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

    NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive ServerShare, True, False
    ' NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive "X:", True, False
    ' Use above line to disconnect a mapped network drive
    Set NetworkObject = Nothing

End Sub


is it not able to do this without having to use a username and password ? Can it not just use the users SSO at all?

Username and Password are both optional parameters of MapNetworkDrive. You can remove them from this code, i.e. NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "X:", ServerShare, False
